# Laravel - getting items from relationship if they exists in collection

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am having `articles` and `features` tables and a pivot `article_feature` table. Features table have items like `commenting`, `like`, `share`. I also have tables `comments` and `likes` . 
In my function I should get all features for an article and then get all the results from relationships. Basically tell laravel get me all features and for each feature give me all results. The problem is that `features` table is not connected with tables like `comments` and `likes`. I was wondering if that is possible with hasManyThrough but not sure how to do it since there could be many features. I have set up relationships in `Article` model like this:

```
public function comments()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Comment');
  }

public function features()
  {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Feature');
  }

public function likes()
  {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Like');
  }
```

This is my function:

```
public function latest(){
    $result = Article::with('comments.user')->where('publish', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(15);
    $user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate();

    foreach($result as $article){
      $articles[$article->id] = $article;
      $articleFeatures = $article->features()->get()->toArray();

      if (count($articleFeatures) != 0) {
        $articles[$article->id]['features'] = $articleFeatures;
        $articles[$article->id]['likes'] = $article->likes()->get();
        $articles[$article->id]['comments'] = $article->comments()->get();
      }



    return $articles;
  }
```

Comment: So from your **features** result you want to get the **comments** and **likes** of the **feature**d Article, something like feature->articles->comments?

Comment: It would have to be for example if article->feature->comments exist get all article->feature->comments.

Comment: Do you have a relationship between a **feature** and **comment** or it's only from the Article model?

Comment: So far it is only from Article model